# Would it be safe to store/cache casted pointer in baseclass?

Tags: c++, templates, casting

Basically i have a base class "base" and a derrived class "derived" that is a template.

```
class base
{
  ...
};

template<typename T>
class derived : base
{
  ...
};
```

And I often have to cast to the derived type using static_cast. Is there anyway i can store the returned pointer in base (void*?), so i later on only would need to do a quick reinterpret cast ?

Comment: What's 'quicker' with a `reinterpret_cast` vs. a `static_cast` ??

Comment: Casting from base to derived is a pretty big code smell...

Comment: Could abstract classes do it for you?  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr142.htm

Comment: @Alex from what i have understood is using a shared base the only way to store templated classes in a collection. I might be wrong but then i am happy for other solutions.

Comment: @DavidJensen The next step is to add some virtual functions to your base and derived classes so you don't need to cast. That said there are situations where casting is still the best option.

Comment: @DavidJensen Also, as has already been suggested, there is no speed difference between static_cast and reinterpret_cast.

Comment: You should use a `dynamic_cast`, as it ensures the type is correct. However, if you're using polymorphic design, then you must design polymorphically. Virtual functions are the solution here, not casting. Also, don't forget your virtual destructor.

Comment: How is there no speed difference when looking at the assembly static obviously does something and reinterpret does nothing? Since it is a template i obviously know what the type is.

Comment: Let me check something... You are storing `derived` templated on multiple different classes in a collection, right?

Comment: Then *Since it is a template i obviously know what the type is* doesn't make any sense. Under single inheritance, static and reinterpret should do almost the same thing and optimised to exactly the same thing in most circumstances.

Comment: To be able to use a template at all, you need to ascociete it with a certain type, therefore i must know the type.

Comment: Yes, but if you're storing multiple types along side each other in the same container, how do you know which one is which?

Comment: When i use them i am already in templated functions where i have this type X that i know they use. When i am using them elsewhere i call function pointers stored in the based class that are lambdas generated via templated code.

Comment: If static cast and reinterpret cast are compiled to identical assembly code (basically nothing), you "can" use one instead of the other (that is, get away despite the undefined behavior). It makes zero sense but you can. If they are not compiled to the same code,you can not substitute, because only one of these variants is correct, and you know which one. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: I know i cant substitute, thats why im storing the result of static_cast and not doing reinterpret_cast directly.

Comment: You can cast any pointer to `void*` and back to the original type.